# How to declare'n'run lambda in a single expression in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, syntactic-sugar

Like almost all self-respecting projects, my own one also have macro to check some conditions in Debug mode:

```
#ifndef NDEBUG
#  define DCHECK(x) if (!(x)) { ... }
#else
#  define DCHECK(x)
#endif
```

But now I want to `DCHECK()` some complex conditions, like file permissions:

```
...
auto has_permissions = [fd] {
  struct stat st;
  if (fstat(fd, &st) == 0) {
    return (st.st_mode & (S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR)) == (S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
  }
  return false;
};
DCHECK(has_permissions());
...
```

Also, I don't want to pollute my code with lambdas which are not used anywhere besides a sole `DCHECK()`, since in Release mode they will be marked as unused variables.

So the question is: is there a compact way to write `DCHECK()` statement that declares, runs and checks any complex condition?

**P.S.** It's not a mandatory to use lambdas - it's just my proposal.

**P.P.S.** `DCHECK()` may be reimplemented, but all already existing invocations should still work without modifications.

Comment: Have you tried creating a template function taking a callable type (which is then called with no args). You could provide a  explicit specialization taking a plain bool for the existing bool uses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define the lambda within the `DCHECK` macro *and* invoke it

```
DCHECK(([]{ return false; }()));
//                         ^^
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2f389f5ab18edeaf)